# Swift Sound signal should make background music quieter

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, avfoundation

in my App I want to play a sound. I managed to keep the background music playing, but my sound signal is now suddenly much too quiet compared to the background music. How can I make the background music quieter for a short time?

Here is my code so far:

```
import AVFoundation 


var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playSound(){
    do{
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "wav")
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
    }catch{
        //ERROR
    }
}
```